# Modifying Code Output by a React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am using a React library which outputs an svg-icon.  I would like to style that icon using linear-gradients.  To do so, I need to modify the code that is output.  Here is a simplified schema showing what I would like to change

**Current Output**

```
<svg>
  <path></path>
</svg>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient>
      <stop />
      <stop />
    <linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path></path>
</svg>
```

In other words, I need to some code inject into the `svg` tags that get output.

Is it possible to do this with React?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: It may be possible to tell if you provide the library name.

Comment: `react-icons`:  https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons 

If that doesn't work, then perhaps this library:  https://github.com/jacobwgillespie/styled-icons